# Resume a python script based on a certain keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

If I try to break a script when it hits a keyword, as in "d", I can try like:

```
import string

charset = string.ascii_lowercase
for item in charset:
    if item == "d":break
    print(item)
```

I can also let a script ignore a keyword, as in "d" by trying like the following:

```
import string

charset = string.ascii_lowercase
for item in charset:
    if item == "d":continue
    print(item)
```

Now I'm trying to figure out if there is any way I can resume a script when it encounters a certain keyword, as in "d".

***EDIT:*** To be clearer, I wish to put a keyword within the loop so that the script will start printing the rest after the keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd adjust your condition accordingly to `continue` on all letters lower than `'d'`:

```
for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    if char < 'd':
        continue
    print(char)
```

More pythonic would be to create a sequence which omits those letters to begin with:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

for char in dropwhile(lambda c: c < 'd', string.ascii_lowercase):
    print(char)
```

```
for char in filter(lambda c: c != 'd', string.ascii_lowercase):
    print(char)
```

```
from itertools import takewhile

for char in takewhile(lambda c: c < 'd', strings.ascii_lowercase):
    print(char)
```

And of course, instead of doing this in a loop, it'd be even more pythonic to do something like this:

```
print(*takewhile(lambda c: c < 'd', string.ascii_lowercase), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import string

run = False

charset = string.ascii_lowercase
for item in charset:
    if item == "d":
        run=True
    if run:
        print(item)
```

Is this what you are looking for?